# Photoshop API - Fit image to specific size

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to fit an image to a certain size with the Photoshop API.

I created an Action JSON file which I use with the Photoshop API and send to this endpoint: *https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/actionJSON*

However this object does not do anything (doesn't work):

```
{
   _obj: "javaScriptOptionsClass",
   height: { _unit: "pixelsUnit", _value: 1440.0 },
   limit: false,
   message: "Fit Image action settings",
   width: { _unit: "pixelsUnit", _value: 1080.0 },
},
```

How can I fit an image with the action JSON to certain dimensions?

Everything normal works, I have tested different other actions which work but not this one.

Thanks in advance!